# Connection to server failed error

Tags: connection

There is a website of a browser game [Tanki Online](http://tankionline.com). I can open the website but when I try to connect from either Ubuntu or Linux Mint to any of their servers for playing it gives me an error message like `connection to server ... failed` or something similar. I assume this is the firewall issue but any solution which I get doesn't help me.

Any idea on how to solve it is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked out the link you gave and I have no problems with Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid, Firefox 15.01 and Shockwave Flash V11.2 r202.

This game relies on Flash Player in your browser. Which browser are you using (I would assume Firefox)? Have you tried another browser (eg Chrome)? I also suggest you try reinstalling/upgrading Flash.

Comment: I tried many browsers on two linux systems: Ubuntu 11.10 and Mint 12. Both with any browser give the same error. Second laptop with Mint 12 goes without any problems. In the game forum they discuss the same problem for some Linux systems but no solution has been found yet.

Comment: I have just updated to Ubuntu 12.04 but no change.